# Why does toolchain name have separate OS and EABI fields.?

Tags: linux, gcc, toolchain, abi, crosstool-ng

For eg. arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi
Now, once the OS i.e Linux is fixed, the C Library will be fixed (GLibc) and hence the calling convention and ABI being followed will be fixed. What is the requirement of 4th field i.e. ABI separately? Can a toolchain use a different ABI from the one used by underlying OS and LIBC. In that case how will libraries compiled by the said toolchain run on the OS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's more or less a matter of historical reasons, a.k.a [the holy wars about the sacred operating system's name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU/Linux_naming_controversy). What you call the "toolchain name" is actually called the [Target Triplet](http://wiki.osdev.org/Target_Triplet), and as it name imply, it has *three* fields, not either more or less. In your example case, the fields would be:

- Machine/CPU: `arm`
- Vendor: `unknown`
- Operating System: `linux-gnueabi`

Take another reference example I've already faced: `i686-elf-gcc`, which is used for [hobbyist operating system development](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hobbyist_operating_system_development):

- Machine/CPU: `i686-elf`
- Vendor: `unknown` (implicit)
- Operating System: `none` (implicit; the compiler is actually a [freestanding](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/preface/hosted_and_free_standing.html) [cross compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler), used for the development of [operating system kernels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(operating_system)), thus the code it outputs expects no underlying OS, as the output code is the OS itself!).

This is just a matter of confusion originating from the fact that the fields may (and *do*) use the `-` character, which is used to separate the fields, too. In your case, the OS is considered to be `linux-gnueabi`, otherwise known as the GNU operating system with the Linux kernel using the [Embedded ARM ABI](https://wiki.debian.org/ArmEabiPort). The Linux Kernel [has historically been one of the most portable pieces of software in the world](http://www.makelinux.net/books/lkd2/ch19lev1sec1), so it's expected to be portable to other ARM ABIs, although I'm only aware of the EABI...

Comment: Thanks! so Linux using Embedded ABI it is. One more doubt is how ABI is tied to C std Library(GLibc for eg.) and the OS.. (In this particular case, I think LibC has been compiled using a compiler which uses EABI convention and the machine code generated by this compiler also uses EABI..? Is it?

Comment: @BhavikAmeta: You're (apparently) using a cross-compiler (see link in my answer), so your compiler is probably *not* running on ARM EABI, but generating code for it. The target triplet has actually nothing to do with the C library. That wouldn't make too much sense, after all, because C has nothing to do with the ABI. For example, if you write a program in assembly, what would be the C library field set to? `unknown`? Then we would need (yet) another toolchain for the assembly! Anyway, there're [many other C libraries for GNU/Linux apart from Glibc](http://www.etalabs.net/compare_libcs.html).